# how to set the header when sending CoAP request using CoAP plugins Copper in Firefox

Tags: coap

I would like to send CoAP request using CoAP plugins Cooper in Firefox, but have no idea how to add header to this request. Does anyone have an idea how to add header to the request using CoAP plugins Cooper.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CoAP cannot have a Header. It only has set of options. Copper allows you to set some default options for a request.